# No output from the program

Tags: c

In our student class we are building a small program to process the data from Oil & Gas Industry. The program at a rough condition, but we learn a lot through the project.

The program is compiled this way

In the below sections you can find the whole code of the source files. Here is the compilation routine:

1. `gcc -fPIC -c parser.c -o parser.o`
2. `gcc -shared parser.c -o parser.dll`
3. `gcc -c well.c - o well.o`
4. `gcc -c main.c -o main.o`
5. `gcc main.o well.o -L. -lparser -o well.exe`

Then we execute it this way: `well.exe "WELL_DATA.csv" "NUM OF WELL TO FIND" >> well.log`

**The problem** the execution starts, but the output from `fprintf` appears just sometimes, but usually not... We hope you can help us resolve our problem

`main.c` file content

```
#include"well.h"

FILE* input;
struct WELL* head = NULL; //the head of the list
struct TNode* tree = NULL;


int main(int argc, char *argv[3]) {
    CBUFFER* buffer = malloc(sizeof(CBUFFER));
    buffer->len = BUFFER_SIZE;
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    struct WELL* instance = NULL;
    
    
    while(buffer->len != 0){
        flushBuffer(buffer);
        getNextLine(input, buffer);
        if (buffer->len == 0)
            break;
        parseData(buffer);
        instance = createWell(buffer);
        addWell(instance, &head);
    } 

    instance = getWell(argv[2], head);
    if (instance != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout,"NAME = %s\tLIFT_TYPE = %i\tMONTHLY_OIL_FLOW_RATE = %.2f\n", instance->name, instance->prodMethod, instance->oil.monthly);
    else fprintf(stdout,"No such well\n");
    freeList(head);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

In the following sections you can find the rest of the code. Here is the `parser.c` which processes the data:

```
#include "parser.h"

unsigned short getNextLine(FILE* input, CBUFFER* buffer){
    //printf("Getting next line\n");
    unsigned short  len = 0;
    char symbol = fgetc(input);
    if (!input || !buffer)
        return 0;
    while ((symbol != '\n' && (symbol != EOF))){
       //
        *((buffer->data) + len) = symbol;
        symbol = fgetc(input);
        len++;
    } 
    *((buffer->data) + len) = '\n';
    buffer->len = len;
    buffer->index = 0;
    return buffer->len;
}


unsigned short parseData(CBUFFER* buffer){
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (buffer->len + 1));
    unsigned short i = 0;
    unsigned short j = 0;
    while (*((buffer->data) + i) != '\n'){
        if (*((buffer->data) + i) == '\0' || *((buffer->data) + i) == '\r' || *((buffer->data) + i) == '\v' ||
                *((buffer->data) + i) == '\t' || *((buffer->data) + i) == '\f')
            i++;
        else{
    
            if (*((buffer->data) + i) == ';')
                *(temp + j) = '\0';
            else
                *(temp + j) = *((buffer->data) + i);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    *(temp + j) = '\n';
    flushBuffer(buffer);
    i = 0;
    while (*(temp + i) != '\n'){
        *((buffer->data) + i) = *(temp + i);
        i++;
    }
    *((buffer->data) + i) = '\0';
    free(temp);
    buffer->len = i;
    return buffer->len;
}

char* getValue(CBUFFER* buffer)
{
    int i = buffer->index;
    int j = buffer->index;
    char c;

    for (; i <= buffer->len; i++)
    {
        c = buffer->data[i];
        if (c == '\0')
        {
            char* newValue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i - buffer->index + 1)); 
            for (; j <= i ; j++) 
            {
                newValue[j - buffer->index] = buffer->data[j];
            }
            newValue[j - buffer->index] = '\0';
            buffer->index = i + 1;
            return newValue;
        }

    }
    return NULL;
}

DATE getDate(char* input, char delimeter){
    DATE date;
   
    unsigned short number = 0;
    char c = input[0];

    for(unsigned short i = 1, j = 0; i < 12; i++){
        number = number * 10 + atoi(&c);
        c = input[i];
        if((c == delimeter) || (c == '\0')){ 
            if (j == 0) date.day   = number;
            if (j == 1) date.month = number;
            if (j == 2){ 
                date.year   = number;
                break;
            }
            number = 0;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return date;
}


int flushBuffer(CBUFFER* buffer) {
    unsigned short i = 0;
    while( i < buffer->len){
        *((buffer->data)+i) = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    buffer->len = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

And the part which defines the well-object we work with `well.c`:

```
#include "well.h"


struct WELL* createWell(CBUFFER* pbuffer) {
    struct WELL* instance = malloc(sizeof(struct WELL));
    char * nextValue = getValue(pbuffer);
    unsigned i = 0;
    while ( nextValue != NULL){
        setProperty(instance, i, nextValue);
        i++;
        nextValue = getValue(pbuffer);
    } 
    instance->next = NULL;
    return instance;
}

unsigned setProperty(struct WELL* instance, unsigned prop_index, char* value) {
    switch(prop_index){
        case 0: 
                setWellName(instance, value);
                break;
        case 1:
                setWellDate(instance, getDate(value, '/'));
                break;
        case 2: 
                setProductionMethod(instance, value);
                break;
        case 3: 
                setFormation(instance, value);
                break;
        case 4: 
                setPump(instance, value);
                
                break;
        case 5: 
                setProduction(instance, OIL,    MONTH,          atof(value));
                
                break;
        case 6:
                setProduction(instance, OIL,    YEAR,           atof(value));
                break;
        case 7:
                setProduction(instance, OIL,    COMMULATIVE,    atof(value));
                break;
        case 8: 
                setProduction(instance, WATER,  MONTH,          atof(value));
                break;
        case 9: 
                setProduction(instance, WATER,  YEAR,           atof(value));
                break;
        case 10:
                setProduction(instance, WATER,  COMMULATIVE,    atof(value));
                break;
        // PAY ATTENTION THAT cases from 11 to 13 are skipped!
        // THIS IS BECAUSE WE DON'T NEED m3 PARAMETERS as it is
        // AND CAN CALCULATE THEM from tons using density parameter 
        case 14: 
                setProduction(instance, MIX,  MONTH,            atof(value));
                break;
        case 15:
                setProduction(instance, MIX,  YEAR,             atof(value));
                break;
        case 16:
                setProduction(instance, MIX,   COMMULATIVE,     atof(value));
                break;
        case 17: 
                setProduction(instance, MIX,  MONTH,            atof(value));
                break;
        case 18:
                setProduction(instance, MIX,  YEAR,             atof(value));
                break;
        case 19:
                setProduction(instance, MIX,  COMMULATIVE,      atof(value));
                break;
    }
    return 0;     
}

unsigned addWell(struct WELL* instance, struct WELL** head) {
    
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = instance;
    } else {
        struct WELL* tmp = *head;
         while (tmp->next){
            tmp = tmp->next;
        } 
        tmp->next = instance;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct WELL* getWell(char* key, struct WELL* head) {
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;
    struct WELL* currentWell = head;
    while (strcmp(currentWell->name, key) != 0) {
        if (currentWell->next == NULL) return NULL;
        currentWell = currentWell->next;
    }
    return currentWell;
}

char* setWellName(struct WELL* instance, char* value) {
    strcpy(instance->name, value);
    return instance->name;
}

char* setFormation(struct WELL* instance, char* value) {
    strcpy(instance->devFormation, value);
    return instance->devFormation;
}

char* setPump(struct WELL* instance, char* value) {
    strcpy(instance->pump, value);
    return instance->pump;
}

DATE setWellDate(struct WELL* instance, DATE date) {
    instance->startDate.day = date.day;
    instance->startDate.month = date.month;
    instance->startDate.year = date.year;
    return instance->startDate;
}

WLIFT_TYPE setProductionMethod(struct WELL* instance, char* value) {
    if (!strcmp(value, "flush"))
        instance->prodMethod = FLUSH;
    if (!strcmp(value, "gaslift"))
        instance->prodMethod = GAS_LIFT;
    if (!strcmp(value, "pump"))
        instance->prodMethod = PUMP;
    return instance->prodMethod;
}

double setProduction(struct WELL* instance, WFLUID fluid, WPERIOD period , double value) {
    if (fluid == OIL) {
        if (period == MONTH) {
            instance->oil.monthly = value;
            return instance->oil.monthly;
        } else if (period == YEAR) {
            instance->oil.year = value;
            return instance->oil.year;
        } else if (period == COMMULATIVE) {
            instance->oil.commulative = value;
            return instance->oil.commulative;
        }
    } else if (fluid == GAS) {
        if (period == MONTH) {
            instance->gas.monthly = value;
            return instance->gas.monthly;
        } else if (period == YEAR) {
            instance->gas.year = value;
            return instance->gas.year;
        } else if (period == COMMULATIVE) {
            instance->gas.commulative = value;
            return instance->gas.commulative;
        }
    } else if (fluid == WATER) {
        if (period == MONTH) {
            instance->water.monthly = value;
            return instance->water.monthly;
        } else if (period == YEAR) {
            instance->water.year = value;
            return instance->water.year;
        } else if (period == COMMULATIVE) {
            instance->water.commulative = value;
            return instance->water.commulative;
        }
    } else if (fluid == MIX) {
        if (period == MONTH) {
            instance->liquid.monthly = value;
            return instance->liquid.monthly;
        } else if (period == YEAR) {
            instance->liquid.year = value;
            return instance->liquid.year;
        } else if (period == COMMULATIVE) {
            instance->liquid.commulative = value;
            return instance->liquid.commulative;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (meaning not all of the code you have, just the parts the people who are going to answer your question need).

Comment: I didn't investigate the whole code, but you basically are saying two things: "My program does not do what it's supposed to do" and "my `print()` command does not show what it's supposed to show". As far as the first issue is concerned: did you debug your program (using a breakpoint) and are you sure your breakpoint gets hit? For the second one: Windows does not immediately show the output of the print-command, but puts it in an output buffer. In case you're working in Windows, empty the output buffer immediately after performing the print-command.

Comment: @Dominique thx for your response! Yes, you got to the point about the question we have posted. The main problem is that the program outputs the result "from time to time", yet the code is correct. From your reply we understood that there can be a delay between the printf output in Windows. But how do we make the process to wait until printf actually finishes its execution before the program goes further? and what is the best way to flush the output buffer if its stdout? thx in advance

Comment: @STUDENTSPETROSCHOOL: you can flush the output buffer, directly after having performed a ´print´ statement.